# Can't display texture with sampler

Tags: swift, macos, metal

I am trying to display a texture loaded with MTKTextureLoader, I have a buffer that stores my vertices coordinates (I build two triangles to have a rectangle in which to display my image), then I have a buffer that stores the texture coordinates of each vertex.
I made a sampler to sample data from my texture, the problem is that I am getting nothing (black image).

**I putted the Swift code just in case my error comes from there, but I think it comes form the Metal code. If you look at my fragment shader, you will see two comments, they show something that I can't understand :**

- If I give the coordinates directly to the sample function, it works (colours the triangles with the color that corresponds to the given coordinates).
- If I give the coordinates I pass to the sampler as color components, it also displays something coherent (triangles coloured in function of the given coordinates).

So it doesn't seem to come from the sampler, nor from the coordinates, that's what I don't understand.

Here is my Swift code :

```
import Cocoa
import MetalKit
import Metal

class ViewController: NSViewController, MTKViewDelegate {

    var device:MTLDevice!
    var texture:MTLTexture!
    var commandQueue:MTLCommandQueue!
    var vertexBuffer:MTLBuffer!
    var vertexCoordinates:[Float] = [
        -1, 1, 0, 1,
        -1, -1, 0, 1,
        1, -1, 0,  1,

        1,-1,0,1,
        1,1,0,1,
        -1,1,0,1,

    ]

    var vertexUVBuffer:MTLBuffer!
    var vertexUVCoordinates:[Float] = [
    0,1,
    0,0,
    1,0,
    1,0,
    1,1,
    0,1
    ]

    var library:MTLLibrary!
    var defaultPipelineState:MTLRenderPipelineState!
    var samplerState:MTLSamplerState!

    @IBOutlet var metalView: MTKView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
        let textureLoader = MTKTextureLoader(device: device)

        metalView.device = device
        metalView.delegate = self
        metalView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 0
        metalView.sampleCount = 4



        texture = try! textureLoader.newTextureWithContentsOfURL(NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("abeilles", withExtension: "jpg")!, options: [MTKTextureLoaderOptionAllocateMipmaps:NSNumber(bool: true)])

        commandQueue = device.newCommandQueue()
        library = device.newDefaultLibrary()


        vertexBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(&vertexCoordinates, length: sizeof(Float)*vertexCoordinates.count, options: [])
        vertexUVBuffer = device.newBufferWithBytes(&vertexUVCoordinates, length: sizeof(Float)*vertexUVCoordinates.count, options: [])



        let renderPipelineDescriptor = MTLRenderPipelineDescriptor()
        renderPipelineDescriptor.vertexFunction = library.newFunctionWithName("passTroughVertex")
        renderPipelineDescriptor.fragmentFunction = library.newFunctionWithName("myFragmentShader")
        renderPipelineDescriptor.sampleCount = metalView.sampleCount
        renderPipelineDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].pixelFormat = metalView.colorPixelFormat
        defaultPipelineState = try! device.newRenderPipelineStateWithDescriptor(renderPipelineDescriptor)
        let samplerDescriptor = MTLSamplerDescriptor()
        samplerDescriptor.minFilter = .Linear
        samplerDescriptor.magFilter = .Linear
        samplerDescriptor.mipFilter = .Linear
        samplerDescriptor.sAddressMode = .ClampToEdge
        samplerDescriptor.rAddressMode = .ClampToEdge
        samplerDescriptor.tAddressMode = .ClampToEdge
        samplerDescriptor.normalizedCoordinates = true

        samplerState = device.newSamplerStateWithDescriptor(samplerDescriptor)
        metalView.draw()






        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func drawInMTKView(view: MTKView) {

        let commandBuffer = commandQueue.commandBuffer()
        let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor(metalView.currentRenderPassDescriptor!)
        commandEncoder.setRenderPipelineState(defaultPipelineState)

        commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer, offset: 0, atIndex: 0)
        commandEncoder.setVertexBuffer(vertexUVBuffer, offset:0, atIndex:1)
        commandEncoder.setFragmentSamplerState(samplerState, atIndex: 0)
        commandEncoder.setFragmentTexture(texture, atIndex: 0)
        commandEncoder.drawPrimitives(MTLPrimitiveType.Triangle, vertexStart: 0, vertexCount: 6, instanceCount: 1)

        commandEncoder.endEncoding()
        commandBuffer.presentDrawable(metalView.currentDrawable!)
        commandBuffer.commit()

    }

    func mtkView(view: MTKView, drawableSizeWillChange size: CGSize) {
        // view.draw()
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }


}
```

Here is my Metal code :

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;


struct VertexOut {
    float4 position [[position]];
    float2 texCoord;
};


vertex VertexOut passTroughVertex(uint vid [[ vertex_id]],
                                  constant float4 *vertexPosition [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                  constant float2 *vertexUVPos [[ buffer(1)]]) {

    VertexOut vertexOut;
    vertexOut.position = vertexPosition[vid];
    vertexOut.texCoord = vertexUVPos[vid];
    return vertexOut;
}

fragment float4 myFragmentShader(VertexOut inFrag [[stage_in]],
                                 texture2d<float> myTexture [[ texture(0)]],
                                 sampler mySampler [[ sampler(0) ]]) {


    float4 myColor = myTexture.sample(mySampler,inFrag.texCoord);
    // myColor = myTexture.sample(mySampler,float2(1));
    // myColor = float4(inFrag.texCoord.r,inFrag.texCoord.g,0,1);

    return myColor;
}
```

Comment: Your code works on my system. Which version of OS X and Xcode are you using?

Comment: @warrenm I am on the latest public version of El Capitan (10.11.2), latest public version of Xcode (7.2).

Comment: When you say that it works, do you mean that it displays an image ?

Comment: There is something wired, since you told me that it works for you, I tried with an other image and it works..... sort of. Actually, for this other image, it works but only when I enlarge the window. When I downsize the window, it fades to black. I would say that it has something to do with bitmaps, because if I set the sampler mipFilter to .Linear, it does this fading, but if I set it to .Nearest, there is a point where, instead of fading, it suddenly disappears. It would look like there is nothing in the other mipmap level.

Comment: (I think the reason why I was able to get it work with the second image is that the image is smaller, therefore at standard screen size it's the "good" mipmap level that is displayed).

Comment: Here's what I think is happening. You're allocating space for mipmaps but not actually generating them. Your sampler configuration (mipmap-linear) causes the texture to be sampled at the base level as long as the texture is small relative to the rect on the screen, but if you feed in a larger texture, it starts sampling down the mip stack, picking up all-black pixels, which are then blended together to either darken the source image or cause the output to be entirely black. Use a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to generate a complete set of mipmaps.

Comment: @warrenm I thought that the MTKTextureLoader alone was enough to create mipmaps ! I will try your solution, thank you! I still can't understand why the app is so slow, as you saw my code, am I doing something wrong in the drawInMTKView ? Because when looking at the Xcode FPS performance jauge, I see that most of the time is spent on the CPU.

Comment: I'm not seeing high CPU usage in my copy of your code, but regarding mipmaps, the docs say "a full set of mipmap levels are allocated for the texture when the texture is loaded, and it is your responsibility to generate the mipmap contents."

Comment: @warrenm I followed your advice and it works now ! Thank you ! Actually, high CPU usage was happening when I was resizing the window and was due to currentRenderPassDescriptor call on Metal View, but that seems okay as there is also this effect (but less accentuated) in Apple examples. One last question, although it's quite a lot subjective, does it seem normal to get less than 60 FPS (about 40) when displaying a 18 mpx image in full screen with my method ? (13". Retina MacBook Pro)

Comment: That is indeed a subjective question, but if you have performance concerns, consider filing a bug with Apple describing your full system configuration and including a sample project if possible.

Comment: @warrenm Thank you so much, yes I probably will, actually, when using Instruments, I see that most of the time is passed in the buffer commit method. I love your website by the way, it is really helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating space for mipmaps but not actually generating them. [The docs say](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MetalKit/Reference/MTKTextureLoader_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Texture_Loading_Options) that when specifying `MTKTextureLoaderOptionAllocateMipmaps`, "a full set of mipmap levels are allocated for the texture when the texture is loaded, and it is your responsibility to generate the mipmap contents."

Your sampler configuration causes the resulting texture to be sampled at the base mipmap level as long as the texture is small relative to the rect on the screen, but if you feed in a larger texture, it starts sampling the smaller levels of the mipmap stack, picking up all-black pixels, which are then blended together to either darken the image or cause the output to be entirely black.

You should use the [`-generateMipmapsForTexture:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MTLBlitCommandEncoder_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MTLBlitCommandEncoder/generateMipmapsForTexture:) method on a `MTLBlitCommandEncoder` to generate a complete set of mipmaps once your texture is loaded.